# IIS7.5 Sort SSL certificate list

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

When trying to add an SSL binding to a site in IIS7.5 the SSL Certificate drop down list is not sorted alphabetically and it become quite cumbersome when we have a lot of them.  Is there any script we can run that changes the order of this list?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but **no**!
You cannot run a script to change the order of the certificates in the list shown in the **Bindings** prompt

When you enumerate the contents of a certificate store in Windows, the resulting list is sorted lexicographically by the `Thumbprint` attribute on the certificates, meaning that a certificate where the first byte of the thumbprint is `FF` will always be listed before one starting with `3A`, which will be listed before `01` and so on.

If it sounds like nonsense, try to whip out PowerShell with Administrator credentials and watch how certificates arrange when you query the contents of a certificate store:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

The default output format shows the Thumbprint and Subject values for all certificates in the computers Personal Store - ordered from FF to 00

So, you would have to be able to control the resulting thumbprint on a certificate in order to achieve this. You could keep re-keying and re-signing your certificates until they are ordered as you please, but that's practically impossible - the idea itself seems to be a case of "working against the system"

---

*I have no documentation to support this claim, but having worked on **a lot** of IIS installations on Windows Server 2008R2, this is the only pattern I've recognized.*